# Invalid parameter number when using whereNotIn in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I want to print the list of option from database on my blade, which I want to get all list except the option that already selected. So what I've already do is getting the selected option (which is saved on another table) as an array:

```
$ctg_id[] = [];
foreach($vendor->category as $item){
  $ctg_id[] = [$item->category_id];
}
```

Then finally print it:

```
$category = ItemCategory::whereNotIn('id',$ctg_id)->get();
```

But it return an error that says:
"SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select * from `category_item` where `id` not in (4, 3, ?))" Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using double dimensional array, you need to change it to one dimensional:

```php
$ctg_id = [];
foreach($vendor->category as $item){
  $ctg_id[] = $item->category_id;
}
```

Recommend to use [method-pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck) like this:

```php
$category = ItemCategory::whereNotIn('id', $vendor->category->pluck('category_id'))->get();
```